# What is $E$ in below equation? Does it represent total energy or kinetic energy(De-broglie equation for uncharged particle like neutron.)

Tags: atomic-physics

De-broglie equation for uncharged particle:
$$\lambda= \frac{h}{\sqrt{2mE}}$$
Where,
$\lambda$ = wavelength

$h$ = planks constant

$m$ = mass of uncharged particles

Answer (score 1):

$E$ here is the kinetic energy, not the total energy.

The original formula is $\lambda=h/p$, and then $p$ is obtained from the (non-relativistic) formula $E={1\over 2} m v^2 = p^2/2m$

Answer (score 0):

The de Broglie wavelength is the wavelength, $λ$, associated with a massive particle (i.e., a particle with mass, as opposed to a massless particle) and is related to its momentum, $p$, through the Planck constant, $h$:

$$\lambda= \frac{h}{p}$$

For non-relativistic particle, Total energy of free particle
$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}\Rightarrow p=\sqrt{2mE}$$
$$\lambda= \frac{h}{\sqrt{2mE}}$$

---

In relativistic-case, Using two formulas from special relativity, one for the relativistic mass-energy and one for the relativistic momentum

$$p=\gamma m_0 v$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda=\frac{h}{\gamma m_0 v}$$

Comment: Your formula for momentum has the wrong units. For relativistic case. And it's wrong.  A particle at rest should have zero momentum.